# Loading external SWF and last version of FD

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

(I'm working with FlashDevelop)

I'm having issue loading some external swfs in my project. This worked great until a few month back when they switched the preloader integration with :

[Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]

Since then my swf loaded with a Loader() doesn't show.

Any idea of what changed ?

Thanks !

**Code :**

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point

        loadMovie("Dots.swf");
    }

    private function loadMovie(url:String):void {
        var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();

        mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
        mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);

        mLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
    }

    private function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event):void {
        trace("COMPLETE");
        addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
    }

    private function onProgressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        trace("progressHandler: bytesLoaded=" + event.bytesLoaded + " bytesTotal=" + event.bytesTotal);
    }

    private function ioErrorHandler (e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason why the preloader method change can affect further loading. 

Maybe you have broken the preloader in some way - can you show the complete code for this class (and the preloader)?

Comment: I don't think the preloader line is the problem.Event when the only thing that changed is this line ^^

Answer (score 0):

Is "COMPLETE" getting traced out? I can't tell too much from the code you posted here, there could be something else going on, particularly in Dots.swf.

The one thing I see right off the bat is that your loader object may be getting garbage collected, but if it is tracing out "COMPLETE" that definitely is not the case. Try adding loader to the display list right away and see if that makes a difference. eg:

```
var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(mLoader);
```

I do all my work in Flash Develop and have not had any issues with this. If you are able to share more code, or example project, I could investigate further.

Comment: I don't think it's garbage collected because if I apply the same code to an old swf (compiled with FD but before the change) it works.
The COMPLETE event is never called. I just have the progress that goes from 0 to the max (file size). I think it clearly linked to the way FD compile the swfs.